# Possible for Displacement in Material to affect another Object's position?

Tags: displacement

I have created an Ocean in one layer, which is affecting an object using a constraint.  The object bobs up and down with the waves.

But I am baking the Ocean and bringing the bake into the texture channel of a Plane, in another layer, so my Object constraint doesn't work anymore (as I have to disable the original Ocean modifier).

Is there a way to get the position of the displacement on the new Plane, so that I can use this data to move the Object in question?